# Configure Netty SSL client sockets to send SNI header in Android

Tags: sockets, ssl, netty, sni

I'd like to create an SSL/TLS connection using the Netty framework which will send a SNI header together during handshake. My current code looks like this:

SslContext creation:

```
    TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = SimpleTrustManagerFactory.getInstance(
            SimpleTrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    trustManagerFactory.init((KeyStore)null);

    sslContext = SslContextBuilder
            .forClient()
            .sslProvider(SslProvider.JDK)
            // TODO p0: Ensure all the versions we support have this algorithm installed
            .trustManager(trustManagerFactory)
            .build();
```

Then during pipeline creation:

```
    pipeline.addLast(sslContext.newHandler(ch.alloc(), cloud.getHostName(), cloud.getPort()));
```

However the SNI header is NOT sent. What is missing to force Netty to provide SNI in the SSL Client Handshake?

Answer (score 0):

I could set the SNI using `sslContext.newHandler(allocator, SERVER_NAME, PORT)`, it works fine.

Comment: For asking a clarification question (if you need it answered before you can provide a solution)k, the commenting privilege is needed. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead BUt there is an option for users who do not have that privilege yet:

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Comment: I think the part I left is something of an answer, but that might be my lack of knowledge. So if it is not and you cannot [edit] as described above please delete the post.